# Avoid exception when trying to add a entry with a duplicate index in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 models:

- User
- Puzzle
- Solution

A solution represents the first time that a user solved a given puzzle. I only want to record the **first** time - subsequent attempts don't count. The solution has an index on the user-puzzle combination.

My migration looks like this:

```
class CreateSolutions < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :solutions do |t|
      t.integer :time
      t.integer :attempts
      t.references :user
      t.references :puzzle

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :solutions, [:user_id, :puzzle_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

I'm using MySQL. The Puzzle and User models both have: `has_many :solutions`.

In the `solutions_controller.rb`, I have:

```
  def create
    @solution = Solution.new(solution_params)
    @solution.user = current_user
    @solution.puzzle = Puzzle.find(params["puzzle"])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @solution.save
        format.json { render :show, status: :created }
      else
        format.json { render json: @solution.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The problem is that the second time I try to save a puzzle, I get an exception:

> ```
> ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique in SolutionsController#create
> Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry '28-13' for key 'index_solutions_on_user_id_and_puzzle_id'
> ```

**Goal:** I would like for it to just silently ignore subsequent saves, rather than throw an exception.

Here's what I've tried - all in the solutions_controller.rb:

- `if @solution.save(validate: false)...`
- `if @solution.save(:validate => false)...`
- `if @solution.save(false)...`

Ideally, I only want to skip validation for the duplicate index - I would want to catch other errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Solution model, you could add

```rb
validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, scope: :puzzle_id
```

It will run a select query every time you try to save a solution record. If a record exists for the select query solution.save will give error.

Or you could use first_or_initialize

```rb
Solution.where(user_id: current_user.id, puzzle_id: params[:puzzle][:id]).first_or_initialize(solution_params)
```

This will check if a record exists for the given query if it doesn't exist, it will assign the attributes in the where condition and the solution_params.

## update

```rb
def create
    @solution = Solution.where(user_id: current_user.id, puzzle_id: params[:puzzle][:id]).first_or_initialize(solution_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @solution.save
        format.json { render :show, status: :created }
      else
        format.json { render json: @solution.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

if you do it this way no need to check for the error message, if the record already exists in the table it will be assigned to the @solution and the data in solution params won't be assigned. If the record does not exist @solution will be assigned with the data in where condition and solution_params(user_id and puzzle_id values will be taken from what is given in where condition and others from solution_params). If for an attribute data is given in where condition and solution_params, then solution_params value will be taken.

Comment: Thank you - the first `validates_uniqueness_of` approach seems to _catch_ the error, but it could work. I could check if the `@solution.errors.messages[:user_id]` is "has already been taken" and ignore only that case.

Comment: The second approach works too, but I'm confused by it. It works only if I still initialize the model with `@solution = Solution.new(solution_params)` etc. in the controller. But I don't see where I'm actually using the `@solution` that I initialized. My if block now looks like this: `if Solution.where(user_id: current_user.id, puzzle_id: @solution.puzzle.id).first_or_initialize(solution_params) ...` - I'm not calling `@solution.save` any more.

Comment: I have updated my answer please check it out. I believe you don't want to update the record if it already exists right.

Comment: I see now - thanks again. The only thing I had to do differently from your example was to specify `puzzle_id: params[:puzzle]` instead of `params[:puzzle][:id]`. `params` is just POST parameters, so they're simple name/value pairs. Unless there is a way that the puzzle object should be getting expanded that I'm missing?

Comment: my mistake got confused, ideally, it should be sent in solution object as puzzle_id. since it is named as puzzle I thought it might be a puzzle object coming from params.